# addStatusHistoryComment called by Adyen PSP -> generating a lot of backend e-mails: disable?

Tags: orders, email, order-status

We have Sales -> Order COmments -> Enables = YES

We use this for our clients. So we add a comments in backend, tick "inform customer" and everybody is happy

Now we use Adyen PSP. And this PSP adds all the intermediary comment updates using

```
    $status = (!empty($status)) ? $status : $order->getStatus();
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment(Mage::helper('adyen')->__('Payment is pre authorised waiting for capture'), $status);
```

The problem is that because of `Sales -> Order COmments -> Enables = YES` every status update (4!) is also BCC-ed to us. Not the customer.

**So my question**: it is great that they provide this information: but how can one disable the e-mail generation? (whilst leaving the Order Comments functionlaity for customer intact)

[image]

Comment: could you not then set the correct flag to not notify the customer? not sure how it works technically but I guess you could work something out in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a line `$order->setIsCustomerNotified(false);` before `addStatusHistoryComment`.
`